# IONIC Text between two icons

Tags: ionic-framework, icons, styles

I would like to have an ion-item inside a list with a word centered between two icons (one on left side and one on right side) like this:

[image]

I'm not able to achieve this goal, because I have something like that:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" style="text-align: center">
    <ion-icon item-left name="lock"></ion-icon>
       <b>Woman</b>
     <ion-icon item-right name="lock"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

How can I have something like in the first image where the text it's centered correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align` property for center your text like below

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" style="text-align: center">
    <ion-icon item-left name="lock"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label class="centerlabel">Woman</ion-label>
    <ion-icon item-right name="lock"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

**SCSS**

```
.centerlabel {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: this don't work. The output it's exactly like in my case :( the text isn't centered and the two icons are not at the same distance from the left/righ border..

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
   <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-1 style="text-align: left;">
         <ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-10 style="text-align: center;">
         <b>Woman</b>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1 style="text-align: right;">
         <ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item >
    <ion-icon item-left name="lock"></ion-icon>
       <div text-center><b style="margin-left: -20px;">Woman</b></div>
     <ion-icon item-right name="lock"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>  
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: I first used margin too, but I was searching for something more clean then force a margin :) Fortuntely I solved and posted the code in my edited answer.

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that you edited the question and added the solution. Glad your problem is solved